# Persistent counter for every REST call

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

Is there any better way in spring boot that I can maintain a persistent counter in a DB(say, Redis or ES) for every kind of REST call with their corresponding timestamp? (WHAT I am not looking for is calling a function from within every REST call). Probably something like if I can do it before the control is passed to the function corresponding to the REST call, a common portion.

Comment: Have a look at http://metrics.dropwizard.io/3.2.3/manual/index.html. It supports different backends to write the data to, and in connection with Spring Boot afaik you just have to add the library to the classpath to have metrics for your REST endpoints. Though i'm not sure if it supports saving the timestamp of each request. For that you could use a servlet filter.

Comment: The simplest way is to use **web filter**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can implement a custom interceptor.

```
public class MyInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {


    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    // persist your counter here
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) throws Exception {
        super.afterCompletion(request, response, handler, ex);
    // do what you need in the end of the call
    }
```

to make spring-boot invoke your interceptor you should add a configuration class:

```
@Service
@EnableWebMvc
public class MyConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new MyInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/*");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! 
Further questions:
1. How do I tell spring boot to use my interceptor? Is there any config file kind of thing? 
2. And it looks like async call, so it won't add any extra overhead in performance of the actual REST call. Right?

Comment: Sure,
Edited my answer.